# does the pullback of a covering space correspond to the pullback of the corresponding representations of $\pi_1$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Say you have a covering space $C \rightarrow X$ corresponding to some homomorphism $\pi_1(X)\rightarrow S_n$. Suppose you have an arbitrary (continuous) map $f : Y\rightarrow X$. Then we may pull back the cover $C$ to get a cover $C\times_X Y$ of $Y$. Does this cover of $Y$ correspond to the representation

$$\pi_1(Y)\stackrel{f_*}{\rightarrow}\pi_1(X)\rightarrow S_n$$

If so, why?

- will